# conversion from "String" to "Single" Type not working

Tags: vb.net

I have data stored into a string format which is using the comma to separate decimals from integers. The variable "dataPoint" is actually an element of a DataTable object that has been used to retrieve data from a SQLite .db file:

```
dataPoint = MyDataTable.Rows(0)(0) ="0,1563"
```

When I try to make the conversion using the following line of code:

```
convertedDataPoint = Convert.ToSingle(Strings.Replace(dataPoint, ",", "."))
```

... I get the following value:

```
>>> 1563.0
```

rather than

```
>>> 0.1563
```

What's wrong here? How should I convert these data properly?

Comment: can you show where you declared `convertedDataPoint`

Comment: What is your culture setting? Is `,` the decimal point or the thousands separator?

Comment: It is actually an element retrieved as String from a SQLite database. I'm adding a part on the top

Comment: @NicoSchertler you've just solved my issue, I'm working on an Italian OS (CULTURE SETTING: "." to separate thousands and "," to separate decimals) now and as soon as I removed the "Replace" method, the number was converted. If you write this as an answer I'll mark it as solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Convert.ToSingle()` uses the current thread's culture information to parse the number. If you want an invariant approach, you can specify which format the string is in:

```
convertedDataPoint = Convert.ToSingle(dataPoint, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

or the italian one:

```
convertedDataPoint = Convert.ToSingle(dataPoint, new CultureInfo("it"))
```

But don't instantiate a new `CultureInfo` each time. Create it once and use it everywhere you need it.

Anyway, your database should store the number in a consistent way. Preferably as a number, not as a string. If it has to be a string, then use a consistent formatting that does not depend on the computer's language settings.